# JasperException when using f: in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying t learn Spring MVC and my project is buid a jsp form input a product
[image]

I added all jar jstl lib, and here is my taglib

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
```

Here is my form appears bug

```
`<f:form action ="insertProduct.htm" method="GET" commandName="newProduct">
        <table border ="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Product ID</td>
                <td><f:input path="productId"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Name</td>
                <td><f:input path="productName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td><f:input path="price"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><f:input path="description"/><td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>
                    <f:select path="status">
                        <f:option value="true" label="Active"/>
                        <f:option value="false" label="Inactive"/>
                    </f:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Insert"/>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1)"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </f:form>`
```

But i cant fix my bug. Please help me :(

Comment: Is the input inside a form spring tag?

Comment: Yes sir. It is inside a form spring tag

Comment: Then, can you post the torm. I think it might be usefull

Comment: I updated my source. Please help me

Comment: Ok, Looks fine so far. Are you placing the newProduct Object in the Model within the spring controller? and this newProduct object has the productId attribute

Comment: If you are not using _<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>_ then remove it

Comment: But i think my jsp file cant run because of spring taglib form. Now i just want to run my jsp :(